# How to label GeoJSON polygons?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, labeling

I'm using Leaflet combined with GeoJSON features. Is there a way to label GeoJSON features (in this case - polygons)? It should get labels from

```
feature.properties.name
```

This is my code where I think I could insert label:

```
function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.coloring)
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know the format leaflet expects to use.
Example:
OpenLayers expects this GeoJSON format to create a point and give some custom attributes:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {"type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "name":"TRON-02",
                "serial":"TRON002",
                "bearing":0,
                "color":"green",
                "size":15,
                "image":"img/unit_map3.png",
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[-50.06542968749966,-23.749149728383717]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I've created a Geometry (Point) and join my attributes to it. When I send this to OpenLayers, the result will fit in @Aragon's example, using "color" and "name" (as label) to customize the point in map.

Please copy and paste this GeoJSON example in http://json.parser.online.fr/ or use the site to try and validate your own.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I solved it with Leaflet Polygons and Labels, so that you get a floating label on the polygon with its name property.

Suppose:

- you get the json response parsed into the variable json
- there are only simple polygons with no holes in json
- polygon_style holds style options returned by your style function
- labels_layer is a leaflet Layergroup (or directly your map)

Then:

```
for ( var i=0; i < json.features.length; i++ ) {
    feat = json.features[i];
    coords = [];
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < feat.geometry.coordinates[0].length - 1; j++ ) {
        coord = feat.geometry.coordinates[0][j];
        point = [];
        point.push( coord[1], coord[0]);
        coords.push( point );
    }
    labels_layer.addLayer(L.polygon( coords, polygon_style ).bindLabel(feat.properties.name))  ;
}
```

Remarkably oddly enough, GeoJson (actually EPSG:4326) and Leaflet coordinates are swapped in order.

Comment: For those using Leaflet 1.0+, the L.Label has been moved into Leaflet core as L.Tooltip and the plugin has been deprecated. You'd use bindTooltip() instead of bindLabel(). https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label

Answer (score 0):

i think this question is about openlayers.if so, you can use for labelling;

```
var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: "${getColor}",  
    label: "${getLabel}"
  } , {
    context: {
      getColor: function(feature) {
        return feature.properties.color;
      },
      getLabel: function(feature) {
        return feature.properties.name;
      }
    }
  );
```

i hope it helps you...