# Build a leaflet polygon(s) from GeoJSON feature(collection)

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I find it quite practical to work with leaflet Polygon and it would be great to be able to build such objects directly from GeoJSON content. I did not find any Polygon constructor taking neither a GeoJSON object nor a GeoJSON string as input. Is there some method to build a leaflet polygon directly from a feature or an array of polygons from a featurecollection?

Something like:

```
geoJ = GeoJSON object returned/parsed from ajax call
pol = L.polygon( geoJ.features[0] )
bounds = pol.getBounds()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [L.geoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson)?

Comment: I do not want to show the polygon on the map, just process it and use the leaflet class for that.

Comment: As nathansnider suggested, you could easily use `L.geoJson(geoJ)` to perform the conversion. It does not show anything on map as long as you do not explicitly ask Leaflet to do so (map.addLayer). Then you would iterate through each layer (corresponding to each polygon) with `eachLayer()` method.

Comment: L.geoJson does indeed work and provides the getBounds method that I need. It also provides correct coordinates but they are for the entire FeatureGroup. When a collection is used it indeed provides getBounds on each feature, which wondered me a bit until I noticed that the actual layer (which provides no such method) is indeed set to an L.Polygon according to geojson content! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides converting a feature to a Polygon with a dedicated function (see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43120/how-to-label-geojson-polygons/162296#162296)), L.geoJson(geoJ) can be used to get a collection of objects. In case the input geoJ contains polygons, the objects themselves will be set to be L.Polygons, hence the conversion is done automatically. Summing up in both cases:

```
geoJ = GeoJSON object returned/parsed from ajax call
pol = L.polygon( geoJ.features[0] )
bounds = pol.getBounds()
```

and

```
geoJ = GeoJSON object returned/parsed from ajax call
polCollection = L.polygon( geoJ )
polCollection.eachLayer( function(pol) {
    bounds = pol.getBounds()
})
```

give access to the(each) polygon bounds.

Thanks to @nathansnider and @ghybs for the useful comments.